# English version of Hindi proverb 'Ek kaan se suno aur dusre kaan se nikaal do' ('listen with one ear and purge from the other')

Tags: idiom-requests, translation, proverb-requests, hindi

There is a Hindi proverb that goes *'Ek kaan se suno aur dusre kaan se nikaal do'*.

**I would like to know its idiomatic English equivalent.** It literally translates to 'listen with one ear and purge from the other'; it basically means that the person is ignoring what someone is telling them. A subtle distinction should be made, perhaps: this is less about being distracted and more about not paying heed.

Comment: I'm afraid translation is off-topic. See the [faq](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: You **may** be able to stop this question being closed if you attempt a translation yourself and then ask for an equivalent idiomatic English proverb. Try Google Translate, for example.

Comment: Seems already translated on the web [I take negative flak in one ear and out the other, says Deepika Kumari](http://m.indiatoday.in/story/i-take-negative-flak-in-one-ear-and-out-the-other-says-deepika-kumari/1/214269.html)

Comment: @mplungjan........she actually used the idiom and nobody is doing to read  whole article just to see that one line in hindi lost deep inside that article :-)

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped improve the question, but it's still not quite there yet. The requested phrase is still not clearly defined. "Not listening or paying attention to the words that come out of your mouth" is a start, but it will have to be clarified further. Not listening for what reason? Once or always? Is it a good thing or a bad one for the one who's not listening? Is it a good thing or a bad one for the one who's calling him out in it? And so on and so forth. Remember that the question must work, and be 100% unambiguous, with the Indian bit completely removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an idiom

> *to go in one ear and out the other*

[Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=to%20go%20in%20one%20ear%20and%20out%20the%20other) explains that this is when something is "heard but disregarded or quickly forgotten."

**Example**: His mind was made up, so my arguments went *in one ear and out the other.*

Comment: It's hard to get exact equivalents. Note that "in one ear and out the other" does mean disregard, but it may not be wilful. "I tried to tell him she's really no good for him, but it all went in one ear and out the other."